# Submit form value return

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have this source code...

```
<form method="post" id="center" action="">
<br>SpielerName: <?php echo $SpielerName; ?>

<br>Note: <input type="text" name="note" value=<?php echo $Note ?> >
<br>Tore: <input type="text" name="tore" value=<?php echo $Tore ?> >
<br><br><input type="submit" name="submit_eingabemaskeR" value="Abschicken">
```

In the following code I get the values for 'note'...

```
if (isset($_POST["submit_eingabemaskeR"]))  
{
    echo ("<br/>");
    //Note
    echo $_POST["note"];
```

But how can I echo the value of the first field -> SpielerName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpielerName` is not a form field, its just text.
If you want its data submitted you can make a hidden form field with that value.

```
<form method="post" id="center" action="">
<br>SpielerName: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($SpielerName); ?>
<input type="hidden name="SpielerName" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($SpielerName); ?>">

<br>Note: <input type="text" name="note" value=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Note) ?> >
<br>Tore: <input type="text" name="tore" value=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Tore) ?> >
<br><br><input type="submit" name="submit_eingabemaskeR" value="Abschicken">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input.

```
<form method="post" id="center" action="">
<br>SpielerName: <?php echo $SpielerName; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="SpielerName" value=<?php echo $SpielerName; ?> >

<br>Note: <input type="text" name="note" value=<?php echo $Note ?> >
<br>Tore: <input type="text" name="tore" value=<?php echo $Tore ?> >
<br><br><input type="submit" name="submit_eingabemaskeR" value="Abschicken">
```